# S3 buckets randomly unmount on EC2 instance

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, s3fs

My company currently is using S3fs and Ec2 from AWS. We have been mounted our s3 buckets on our Ec2 instances, but after some time (a week, for example) some of the buckets unmount by themselves and our server instances become nearly useless. The error is "Transport endpoint not connected."

S3fs version: 1.61 build from source

FUSE version: 2.84.1 build from source

OS: Linux, Ubuntu 11.04

Is there some kind of safe mechanism for preventing (or at least detecting) these problems?

Comment: more details: OS version? s3fs lib version? mount options? reason to use s3fs instead EBS storage?

Comment: We are running into the same problem. Currently our theory is that it's related to load. We are testing s3fs as a shared filesystem for app servers to share assets, and we've noticed these errors durning load testing. If I find anything more out, I'll update.

Comment: Running 

    s3fs --version
    Amazon Simple Storage Service File System 1.61

    pkg-config --modversion fuse
    2.8.6

I had to build those two versions by hand.
I was able to transfer 10's of thousands of files back and forth today. I'm letting it run on our testing server, however this is looking good, as the previous version would fail after 20 or 30 minutes of sustained io.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Great insight. Hadn't thought about this. But here are 3 precautionary steps we can take:

1) Create an auto-mount so that in the very unlikely event that EC2 is down, S3 gets mounted back on once EC2 comes back via */etc/fstab*

2) or/and if you prefer, create a secondary auto-mount using cron:

```
echo "/usr/bin/s3fs [s3 bucket name] [mountpoint path] -o allow_other" >> automount-s3
sudo mv automount-s3 /usr/sbin
sudo chown root:ubuntu /usr/sbin/automount-s3
sudo chmod +x /usr/sbin/automount-s3

crontab -e
```

add this line

```
@reboot /usr/sbin/automount-s3
```

3) I would also create another hourly cron to check whether S3 is still mounted - this can be done by checking if a dummy file exists in your EC2 path. If the file doesn't exist, cron will do a manual mount by calling "/usr/bin/s3fs -o allow_other [s3 bucket name] [mountpoint path]". It would be good to trigger an email to the admin and log it in the system as well.

Answer (score 1):

s3fs is a nice idea but keep in mind that even though the call to s3 *might* be somewhat internal (or let's say "on their network"), you're still mounting a filesystem over HTTP. That is not going to be stable in the long-run.

Maybe you can re-phrase your question to ask for alternatives and share what you're trying to accomplish by using any kind of (I'm guessing) shared network filesystem. I can see the appeal, but with Amazon EC2 people usually use a *shared nothing* approach and anything extra network-related should be avoided to be able to recycle instances easier, etc..

Happy to extend my answer.